# Why can't my program find the images?

Tags: angularjs

When I go straight into the directory via the browser, in other words localhost:8888/images/mansion-1.jpg, the image appears on the browser, but on the console, it says 404, it can't find the images. Can anybody assist me in figuring out why it cant retrieve the images?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ng-mansions</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body ng-app="ngMansions" ng-controller="mansionsController">

    <!--Nav Bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">mc-mansions</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

  <!--Real Estate Listings-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="mansion in mansions">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img ng-src="images/{{mansion.image}}.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{mansion.address}}</h3>
                    <p><strong>Type: </strong>{{mansion.type}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Description: </strong>{{mansion.description}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Price: </strong>{{mansion.price | currency}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mansionsController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mansionsFactory.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt that you have putted incorrect path

Comment: Pankaj, I am not sure what you meant, but my work environment looks like this: htdocs(folder)->mc-mansions(folder)->data(folder), images(folder), scripts(folder), app.js and index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it says {{mansion.image}} the actual jpg files have to be singular as well, mansion-1.jpg and not mansions-1.jpg. These details really get me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must change this

```
{{mansion.image}}
```

To:

```
"+ {{mansion.image}} +"
```

Comment: Can you show us the mansionsController and mansionsFactory.js. Maybe you can do there some changes